# Integrate a Flutter module into your iOS project but issue is not working in iOS release mode

Tags: ios, flutter, integrate

need help!

Integrate a Flutter module into your iOS project
but facing issue

1 - Integrate a Flutter module into your iOS project not working in iOS release mode - issue is Flutter sdk not available.

2. - Firbase latest sdk not running in flutter project - issue is
     Error output from CocoaPods:

[!] `<PBXGroup path=`Config `UUID=`741F49642135620F001E2961`>`

Comment: Try remove Pods.framework, and perform a pod install and the warnings disappeared.

Comment: I'd a similar problem. But I could even run the flutter module in debug mode. If you can run in debug mode problably is a diferent problem. But if you can't run even in debug mode try looking into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65197799/flutter-pod-install-problem-undefined-method-each-child-for-dir0x00007fa6#answer-65617635